# Отправка картинки post запросом в Python без сохранения

Tags: python, requests, pil

Здравствуйте. У меня есть объект Pil.Image. Надо отправить его на сайт. Если сначала сохранить, а затем сделать так:

```
files = {'photo': open(os.getcwd()+'\\screenshot.png', 'rb')}
a=requests.post(url, files=files)
```

то все работает хорошо. Однако, при попытке сделать вот это:

```
my_file = StringIO()
im.save(my_file, "PNG")
```

я получаю ошибку:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#7>", line 1, in <module>
    im.save(my_file, "PNG")
  File "C:\Users\Riza\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 1698, in save
    save_handler(self, fp, filename)
  File "C:\Users\Riza\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\PIL\PngImagePlugin.py", line 716, in _save
    fp.write(_MAGIC)
TypeError: string argument expected, got 'bytes'
```

Заменив StringIO на ByteIO (пробовал и my_file.getvalue()) ошибки я не получаю, но сервер возвращает пустое поле там, где должна содержаться информация о загруженной фотографии.
Как сделать это правильно? Или есть какие-нибудь другие способы не сохраняя файл его отправить?

Comment: В дополнение к BytesIO, попробуйте `my_file.seek(0)` или имя файла указать: `files = {'photo': ('screenshot.png', my_file.get_value(), 'image/png')}`

Answer (score 1):

Пример сохранения картинки `PIL` в `BytesIO`:

```
import io

# pip install Pillow
from PIL import Image


img = Image.open(os.getcwd() + '\\screenshot.png')
bytes_io = io.BytesIO()
img.save(bytes_io, format='PNG')

files = {'photo': bytes_io)}
rs = requests.post(url, files=files)
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте заменить StringIO на [BytesIO](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.BytesIO)