# Как отправить фото без сохранения на диск?

Tags: python, requests, pillow

вопрос в следующем.

```
//я открываю фото через Pillow
from PIL import Image
photo = Image.open(requests.get(url, stream=True).raw)
//Что то делаю с фото и сохраняю его на диск
img.save('img/image.jpg', quality=100)
Затем с диска фото открываю и отправляю POST запросом на сервер
files = {'media': open('img/image.jpg', 'rb')}
r = requests.post('http://test.test/upload, files=files)
```

Вопрос! Доколе это сохранение на диск будет продолжаться?! Я как то могу отправлять фото на сервер не сохраняя его на диск?

Comment: байты? сохранять фото не файлом, а -> https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/599447/%D0%9E%D1%82%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B8-post-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%B2-python-%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%B7-%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%85%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F